# Empty UITableViewController with async calls

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I am working on using NSURLSession and JSON serialization to fetch content from my site. The async calls and getting the JSON data work perfectly. My issue is, when it comes to displaying the data in the TableviewController, I put an NSLog statement to see if there is data and there is, but that cell.textlable.text never updates. I'm guessing the issue is the threads but I can't figure it out. Can you help?

```
@interface MainTableViewController : 
UITableViewController<LokalModelProtocol>


@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray* arr;

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController
 @synthesize arr;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
LokalModel *lokal = [[LokalModel alloc]init];
lokal.delegate=self;
[lokal downloadItems];

}

-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSMutableArray *)items
{
arr=items;
//NSLog(@"%@", items);
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
// return 1;

return [arr count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mainCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

PostModel *post = [[PostModel alloc]init];
post =[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSLog(@"%@", post.postTitle); ////this outputs the correct strings///////

cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", post.postTitle];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = post.postTitle;///neither of these do//////

return cell;
}

@end





@protocol LokalModelProtocol <NSObject,NSURLSessionDelegate>

+(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSMutableArray*)items;

@end

@interface LokalModel : NSObject

-(void)downloadItems;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData* thedata;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* urlString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL* theUrl;
@property (strong,nonatomic) id<LokalModelProtocol>delegate;
+(void)parseJson:(NSData*)data;

@end





id<LokalModelProtocol>delegate;

@implementation LokalModel;
@synthesize thedata,urlString,theUrl,delegate;

-(void)downloadItems{
NSURL *theUrl = nil;
static NSString* urlString = @"https://balalatet.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
theUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSURLSession *currentSession= [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [currentSession dataTaskWithURL:theUrl completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error){
        [NSException raise:@"error" format:@"%@",error.localizedDescription];
        NSLog(@"error1");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"success");
        [LokalModel parseJson:data];

    }


}];
[task resume];

}

+(void)parseJson:(NSData*)data{

NSArray *jsonResults = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSError *jsonerror;
jsonResults =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonerror];

if (jsonerror)
    [NSException raise:@"json error" format:@"%@",jsonerror.localizedDescription];

NSMutableArray *posts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *jsonElenent =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSMutableDictionary *d in jsonResults)
{
    jsonElenent=d;
    PostModel *thePost=[[PostModel alloc]init];
    thePost.postId= jsonElenent[@"id"];
    thePost.postDate= jsonElenent[@"date"];
    thePost.postDategmt= jsonElenent[@"date_gmt"];
    thePost.postGuid= jsonElenent[@"guid"];
    thePost.postSlug= jsonElenent[@"slug"];
    thePost.postStatus= jsonElenent[@"status"];
    thePost.postSticky= jsonElenent[@"sticky"];
    thePost.postPingStatus= jsonElenent[@"ping_status"];
    thePost.postType= jsonElenent[@"type"];
    thePost.postCommentStatus= jsonElenent[@"comment_status"];
    thePost.postTags= jsonElenent[@"tags"];
    thePost.postTitle= jsonElenent[@"title"];
    thePost.postTemplate= jsonElenent[@"template"];
    thePost.postLink= jsonElenent[@"link"];
    thePost.postMeta= jsonElenent[@"meta"];
    thePost.postModified= jsonElenent[@"modified"];
    thePost.postModifiedgmt= jsonElenent[@"modified_gmt"];
    thePost.postFeaturedMedia= jsonElenent[@"featured_media"];
    thePost.postFormat= jsonElenent[@"format"];
    thePost.postLinks= jsonElenent[@"links"];
    thePost.postAuthor= jsonElenent[@"author"];
    thePost.postContent= jsonElenent[@"content"];
    thePost.postCategory= jsonElenent[@"category"];
    thePost.postExcerpt= jsonElenent[@"excerpt"];
    NSLog(@"%@", thePost.postTitle);
    [posts addObject:thePost];
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [delegate itemsDownloaded:posts];
});
}
@end
```

## Update

my apologies as part of my debugging info is incorrect. the nslog output did not come from the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. in fact the arr array remains empty because the 
    (void)itemsDownloaded:(NSMutableArray *)items
is never called. im sure i setup the protocol correctly. any thoughts on why the MainTableViewControllerClass cant get the data?

## update

so i realized that i forgot to remove the line

```
id<LokalModelProtocol>delegate;
```

that i put right before the @implementation in LokalModel. but now doing so causes an error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" at the line

```
[delegate itemsDownloaded:posts];
```

I aslo tried

```
[self.delegate itemsDownloaded:posts];
```

but it throws the same exception.

## Solved

My protocol method had to be an instance method, and i had it set as a class method.

Comment: Could you check `cell.textLabel` or `cell.detailTextLabel`?, print them, this should also give their frame. Not related but `PostModel *post = [[PostModel alloc]init];
post =[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`should be `PostModel *post = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`, because there is not need in allocating/init one object if you replace it just after.

Comment: thank you for the tips, but in this case the issue lies elsewhere. the NSLog output wast from the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. in fact, the itemsDownloaded:(NSMutableArray *)items function is never called, so ive been working with an empty array.

Comment: That’s different info. Lokal needs to be a strong property. I thought of it, but your question and code implied cellFoRow was called (the comment on the NSLog).

Comment: yes i agree, im not sure what stackoverflow wants in this situation. should i create a new thread later after i investigate some more?  i made lokal a strong property but still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Before return your cell add try to add this code in cellForRowIndexPath

[cell layoutIfneeded];

Comment: That did not work for me. a little side note. if i change numberOfRowsInSection to return a constant, the app crashes due to null pointer. but setting it to [arr count] gives me an empty tableview

Comment: Did you check arr count? Isn’t it Zero? Also did you check your array after copt items in itemsDownloaded?

Comment: ok so i just checked and the count was zero, then i found a mistake in my problem definition. the output i see in the console was not coming from the cellForRowAtIndexPath. so this means that as of now i dont know if the data is being passed correctly. i might just be working with empty arrays. thanks i will update soon

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add a `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` prior to using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` (in viewDidLoad for example)

From the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifie?language=objc

> Important
>   You must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.

Comment: i dont think this is the case because if i create a dummy array of numbers for example, the data is displayed correctly. but in my code, since i fetch data asynchronously, im guessing the issue is that the numberOfRows and cellForRowAtIndexPath methods are completed before i even get data in the array. but i cant figure out how to fix it.